# Scriptlet Prints it Details Twice - JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, scriptlet

I am using jasperserver 5.6.1 community edition. I have designed a report with a scriptlet which is responsible for calculate a sum of some given values. When I run it on iReports, it works fine with no issue. But when I upload it into the jasperserver, Scriptlet seems to run twice. I can't find the reason. And I designed a new report to check whether the fault is in my hands. But no luck issue exists the same. Any idea?

Comment: For every record the detail/sub report will execute and print value. so if in the server you return with 2 records then this will print accordingly.

Comment: @Arasu thanks for replying.. But it was not the case.. cuz when I run it using the iReport it runs fine.. And also I double checked it as well. I will put the result style in the comment and use > mark to show the count vs the id. eg:(100020 is the id and 2 is the count )
100020 > 2
100021 > 4
100022 > 6
     ... > .
it runs something like this where counts 2 , 4 , 6 should be replaced with 1 , 2 , 3 and so on.